# Programming FEN diagrams

Tags: fen, diagram

I'm thinking about creating ANKI flashcards deck with my games positions as a training tool. Is there a way to programmatically (can be whatever programming language, I'll figure it out) generate diagrams from a bunch of FEN strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the online fen2png.com site, calling it with wget or curl:

`curl 'https://fen2png.com/api/?fen=r1b1k1nr/p2p1ppp/n2B4/1p1NPN1P/6P1/3P1Q2/P1P1K3/q5b1%20w%20kq%20-%20-&raw=true' > ~/a.png`

Or you can use a similarly-named python code (which I have not tested):

https://github.com/tikul/fen-to-png/blob/master/fen2png.py